# python threading.lock() not working

Tags: python, multithreading

I created a function to modify a global variable, which adds 1 each time. Then I create 10 threads to call this function; each thread will call the function 10 times. However, the variable's final value is not the same as if I call function 100 times in one thread. Is anything wrong with how I use `threading.lock`? Below is my code:

```
num=0
lockOne=threading.Lock()
def subPro():
    global num
    lockOne.acquire()
    num+=1
    lockOne.release()
```

Comment: Why not post some minimal code which is complete enough to run as-posted and which shows the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not waiting for threads to complete. You have to use [Thread.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

```
import threading

num=0
lockOne=threading.Lock()
def subPro():
    global num
    lockOne.acquire()
    num+=1
    lockOne.release()

def run():
    for i in range(10):
        subPro()

# Start all threads
threads = [threading.Thread(target=run) for x in range(10)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
# Wait for completion
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
print(num)
```